# How to install types for ow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, ecmascript-6

I have installed [ow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ow) by

```
npm i --save ow
```

and when I use it in my TypeScript project, I get

```
/home/ss/projects/m/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:843
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/modules/setPropertyOffer.ts(1,16): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ow' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Doing

```
npm i --save @types/ow
```

doesn't exist.

**Question**

How are the types installed for ow?

Answer (score 1):

As of version `"1.1.0"`

I had to do this `import ow from "ow/dist";`

I think this is because they have not specified the `main` field on their `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the some library's type, you have to make a type file for that.

1. Add the custom typeroot option (`./@types`) in `tsconfig.json`

```js
// tsconfig.json

{
  // ...
  "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./@types"]
  // ...
}
```

2. Create a folder for some library and create a `index.d.ts` file.

```
// ./@types/someLibrary/index.d.ts

declare module 'someLibrary';
```

For ow:

```
// ./@types/ow/index.d.ts

declare module 'ow';
```